# Winamp, SHOUTcast и передача своего текста

Tags: winapi

Здравствуйте.
Есть такая задачка. 
Показывать в бегущей строке winamp'a или в любом другом окне проигрывателя результаты работы одного парсера (написан на php). Результат представляет собой текстовую строку, которую очень хочется показать слушателям радио, которое вещается с помощью SHOUTcast.

Если честно, даже не знаю с какой стороны подступится к этой задачке...

Answer (score 1):

Сам не пробовал, но вреде как должно работать...  
`http://урл-вашего-потока:порт-админки/admin.cgi?pass=ТУТ_ПАРОЛЬ&mode=updinfo&song=ТУТ_ТЕКСТ_КОТОРЫЙ_ВЫВЕДЕТСЯ_У_СЛУШАТЕЛЯ`
можно даже тупо через браузер сделать...
ну, а если надо автоматизация, пишите в комменты, напишу вам программку маленькую для этих целей(бесплатно!!). 
    Я вообще и сам увлекаюсь онлайн аудио/видео трансляцией...

Comment: Если честно - то програмка нужна, от таких услуг не откажусь... Если предложение серьезно - с удовольствием продолжу диалог. Можно здесь, можно в личку..

Comment: не пойму, как тут писать в личку... скайп - metalurgus